# Site dentro de App

Tags: php, java, android

Tenho um site de classificados, preciso criar um app para Android de meu site, não programo em Java, é possível criar um app em que dentro dele seja exibido o site em mobile?

Tipo um iframe do site dentro do app.

Comment: Procura por phonegap/cordova ou Ionic; Acho que é a maneira mais fácil de fazer o que você precisa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma opção é você utilizar o componente [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) do android. Esse componente serve como uma **view** que exibe arquivos HTML. Resumindo, ele "coloca" seu site dentro de um aplicativo [(.apk)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK), e ao executar o aplicativo, ele abre seu site.

Como exemplo, vou supor que você já conhece alguma IDE android e os conceitos básicos.
Você primeiro modificar seu arquivo Layout, ficando assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/webview"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
/>
```

E na sua [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) você chama sua WebView no método [OnCreate](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) você chama seu site.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.main);  
   WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
   myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");  
}
```

E em seu arquivo Manifest, você adiciona permissão para utilizar internet no dispositivo, ficando assim:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Ela suporta diferentes telas, você pode olhar mais [neste link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)

Lembrando que se você precisar de algo mais, você pode utilizar o [PhoneGap](http://www.nanoincub.com.br/blog/tutoriais/tutorial-de-phonegap-iniciando-um-projeto), o [Cordova](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/) ou o [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com) para desenvolver algo melhor. Sobre eles você encontra muito material no Google.

Answer (score 2):

Se você simplesmente quer mostrar o site "dentro do app", basta botar um [componente WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) no app com o endereço do seu site que ele mostrará o site nessa view.

> #### WebView - Class Overview
>
> Uma View para mostrar páginas web. Esta classe é a base sobre a qual pode fazer seu próprio web browser ou simplesmente mostrar conteúdo online dentro de sua Activity. Usa o engenho de renderização WebKit para mostrar as páginas web e inclui métodos para navegar para frente e para trás através do histórico, *zoom in* e *out*, fazer buscas de texto e mais.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um projeto Android e cole o código abaixo e altere a seguinte linha   `webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");` com o endereço do seu site.

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.webview);

       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


    }

}
```

Para maiores detalhes e entender como funciona ou customizar, leia mais neste site: [Exemplos WebView Android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)