# Tornar website em appmobile disponibilizando na playstore

Tags: html, aplicação-web, mobile, app

Preciso de uma solução rápida para uma necessidade urgente,
gostaria de criar um website com linguagens web, e torna-lo um app android e disponibiliza-lo na playstore.

Alguém já fez, ou me diz qual ferramenta ou método de código utilizar??????

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90909/20615) lhe ajuda.

Comment: O nome da ferramenta que você deseja é [Ionic Framework](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-ionic-framework/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar alguns meios.

**Framework7 + Codova:**
Atualmente lhe permite trabalhar com jQuery, VueJS, ReactJS e ate AngularJS (Particulamente é o que eu mais gosto).

**IONIC Framework:**
Você utiliza AngularJS (Não sei dizer se dá para usar outros FM)

Você tambem pode utilizar o **IntelXDK**, que é uma ferramenta da Intel que ajuda no desenvolvimentos de apps hibridos. Lembrando que todos que citei anteriormente, utilizam HTML, CSS e JS para o desenvolvimento.

Da uma olhada nessa [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLup7EJGXDRaOkvy9SkcHSPXldnD2rfCRT), acho que pode te ajuder.

Comment: O Ionic será que é somente com Angular? Pq, vou utilizar (html,css,jquery,php,mysql)

Comment: E quanto ao custo, quero ver tbm um q não seja muito elevado, esse da intel vc recomenda?

Comment: O IONIC é apenas Angular, use Framework7 + IntelXDK, pode baixa-lo, indico sim, da uma olhada na playlist que passei, são aulas minhas mesmo

Comment: Vou ver então, mas me diz uma coisa, o intel xdk sozinho já não faz o efeito, preciso tbm do F7?

Comment: O IntelXDK é uma IDE que lhe possibilidade facilidade no desenvolvimento, o F7 é um Framework HTML, CSS e JS.

Da uma olhada
https://framework7.io/

Caso minha resposta tenha sido suficiente, marcar como resolvido :D

Comment: Mantenho contato, valew! =)