# Gerar APK somente para linkar uma página da web

Tags: android

Desenvolvi um site totalmente responsivo onde já foi testado em diversos celulares, porém gostaria de gerar um APK para poder publicar na Google Store.
Esse aplicativo seria nada mais que "um atalho", quando clicar nele abrir a internet com a URL, consegui utilizar o `WebView`, porém não consigo remover a `MainActivity` em branco.

Utilizei alguns aplicativos geradores de APK, mas a assinatura não fica legal e dificulta a pesquisa na Play Store, então optei por gerar o APK nativo mesmo.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ou tiver uma outra ideia fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Porque não cria uma página html com um iFrame apontando pra sua página e depois empacota com o Cordova!

Comment: Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento mobile, não tinha pensado nisso, estava meio perdido, muito obrigado amigo, ajudou muito

Comment: Eu já passei exatamente porá esta situação e para não ter todo o trabalho de criar um projeto Android e outro Ios fiz isso empacotando com Cordova, funcionou tranquilo!

Comment: Ahhhhh uma dica, procure por PhoneGap Build

Comment: Veja se [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133948/20615) ou [esta outra aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90876/20615) podem lhe ajudar.